# Many MYSQL processes on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

Recently I deploy my parser on server and sometime server start reboot from out of memory, i spectate for memory and find something, exactly after every using parser, (one time on day) ram memory decreases, and after few day server has been crashes. Why MySQL after every stop parser create more trash in RAM?

Screen from htop sorted by use memory

[image: Screen from htop sorted by use memory]

Screen from my.cnf

[image: Screen from my.cnf]

If i reboot the system, amount of process doesn't change, and
systemctl status mysql present that mysql have 28 tasks.

[image]

Comment: Your parser is starting a new MySQL process every time you run the parser.

Comment: But it's not true, i check it with a little script which have same connection type and amount of process or free memory doesn't change. And after system reboot situation not changed, as had 140 mb free before reboot and same amount free memory after reboot.

Comment: I don't see the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in my situation it's setup cron on every reboot before start parsing.

Solve in commands:

```
sudo crontab -e                # cron from sudo permissions

55 23 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r  # setup reboot on 23:55 or 11:55 PM (because parser start on 12:00)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of shutdown twice a day? Not a typical operation.

Comment: Twice? Cron binded on 23:55 and it's one time when linux reboot

Comment: What is the purpose of Cron once a day reboot?

Comment: I don't know, cause I don't find the solve and only solve which help me it's reboot, (after reboot all be right) I setup cron.

Comment: It is likely tuning could help you avoid this daily situation for your instance.  For 4 Free Suggestions - https://mysqlservertuning.com/collections/shop-our-services/products/my-top-4-global-variable-suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you use Innodb as format databases, you can set a buffer limit.

exemple for 4G ram :

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_io_capacity=6000
```

source : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html

Comment: I have 1 GB RAM + from source which you present have:
"innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size configuration option, which has a default of 128M"
And after I write in mycnf you code, situation doesn't change, but it got worse, before: 140 MB AFTER 70MB, i remove this code from, my.cnf, I get 80MB, WTF?))))

Comment: innodb_io_capacity at 6000 might be reasonable for NVME storage.  For SSD, 1500 would be reasonable.  Rotating media at 900 would be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

For a tiny 1GB of RAM, several things need to be tuned:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M
max_connections = 15
query_cache_size = 0
key_buffer_size = 10M
```

And those may be too high